# Online db listing

Tags: javascript, html, split, while-loop, indexeddb

Need help
Writing a list.

```
<div id="ul">
   <li></li>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you decide where the sentence ends? DO you split on `?` `.` `!` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
        function adddbItem(){
            var text = document.getElementById("textInput").value;

            //create array of strings
            var textArray = [];
            textArray = text.split("\.");

            //loop through the array and add each string
            for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++)
            {
                //alert(textArray[i]);
                myIdb.indexedDB.adddbItem(textArray[i]);
            }            
        }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D68Mb/3/

You need to fix the display method though.